# How to fix "Unresolved import call: Cannot find x() in y.dll" in MQL4

Tags: c#, mql4

I'm trying to run a function written in C# on MT4 by means of a dll. The dll compiles correctly, however when I try to run it on MT4 i get an unresolved import call cannot find Add in TestMe.dll

Am following a guide on this link https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/249, 
the dll am using I downloaded it from the page as well. Funny enough when I run the same program using the dll already compiled on the site the code runs fine but when I compile the dll myself using the same code uploaded on the website that's when I start getting the error.

In case you were wondering, I did install the nugget package to enable using RGiesecke.DllExport, also I have the dll located in the mql4 libraries folder and I also enabled "Allow dll imports" in the script common tab.

I don't know if this bit is important but am using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and am using .Net Framework 4.5.2

//This is the C# code for the dll

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {

        private static List<MqlTick> list;

        static Test()
        {
            list = new List<MqlTick>();
        }

        [DllExport("Add", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Add(int left, int right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        [DllExport("Sub", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static int Sub(int left, int right)
        {
            return left - right;
        }

        [DllExport("AddDouble", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static double AddDouble(double left, double right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

        [DllExport("AddFloat", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static float AddFloat(float left, float right)
        {
            return left + right;
        }

    }
}
```

//This is the MQL4 code for running the dll

```
#import "TestMe.dll"
   int Add(int left,int right);
   int Sub(int left,int right);
   float AddFloat(float left,float right);
   double AddDouble(double left,double right);
#import
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Script program start function                                    |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnStart()
  {
   for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
     {
      Print(Add(i,600));
      Print(Sub(400,i));
      Print(AddDouble(654.5,i));
      Print(AddFloat(235.5,-i));
     }
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I always get an error message Unresolved Import function call Cannot find Add in TestMe.dll, I presume it references "Add" cause that's the first function to be called

Answer (score 0):

I've finally figured it out, MT4 only supports 32bit dll whereas MT5 supports only 64bit dll.

In visual studio, my platform target was "Any CPU" this caused MT4 to load the dll but couldn't find any functions within it, setting the platform target to x86 solved the issue.